# Encoded text message

Tags: riddle, cipher

[image: First picture][image: Second picture]

I've revived the above texts from my friend simply called "me". Apparently the text messages tell you everything you need to know. Arrrrrrgh! I told him not to mess with people.

Hint 1:

> The kidnapper is a card game.

Comment: That is two messages. ...and if the only condition is that you don't mention the kidnapper's name, why not obviously send your precise location so there's no guesswork?

Comment: @IanMacDonald if you combine the messages you should be able to figure out where they are ;)

Comment: @Ian MacDonald One group of messages, but sure. Point out every mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Count the number of consecutive letters. For example, `Hhhhhhhhh` $\rightarrow 9$ 
>  
>  Continue this then you get:
>  
>  9 13 9 14 4 3

We might get a message here...

> Perform A1Z26 cipher: IMINDC $\rightarrow$ I'M IN DC 
>  Does it mean you are in **Washington, DC?**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't appear to add one of the pictures. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

Building off u_ndefined's answer:

> The person is in Washington D.C.

Where the king stays:

> The King, aka Elvis Presley is prominently on display at the **Smithsonian National Museum of American History**

The one who kills our children:

> Elvis is famous for revolutionizing the minds of America's youth thus, "killing" the children from the perspective of former generations. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_Presley):
>  *Presley, more than anyone else, gave the young a belief in themselves as a distinct and somehow unified generation—the first in America ever to feel the power of an integrated youth culture.*